# How to push the item to the form array, and bind the value to the checkbox

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am displaying a list of checkboxes wrapped by a button using bootstrap 4:

```
<div class="btn-group-toggle mr-2 p-4" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label
      *ngFor="let day of frequencyDays; let i = index"
      class="btn btn-primary mr-2"
    >
      <input
        [value]="day.id"
        type="checkbox"
        (change)="onChangeCheckbox($event)"
        autocomplete="off"
      />
      {{ day.name }}
    </label>
  </div>
```

Whenever the checkbox is changed I want to update the value of the selected checkbox to the array (**frequencyInterval**) inside the form group.

form group is defined as:

```
this.myForm = this.fb.group({
  frequency: [2, Validators.required],
  frequencyInterval: this.fb.array([]),
});
```

But in my case whenever the button has clicked the method `onChangeCheckbox` is never called.

```
  onChangeCheckbox(e: any) {
    const checkArray: FormArray = this.myForm.get(
      'frequencyInterval'
    ) as FormArray;

    let value = checkArray.value || [];

    alert('e');

    // this.onChangeFrequencyInterval();
  }
```

How to push the item to the `frequencyInterval`, and bind the value to the checkbox if the frequencyInterval already has the items.

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-521z6m)

Answer (score 0):

I added the `click` event to the label, sending the index of `frequencyDays` array:

```html
<form class="form-horizontal" [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <br />
  <div class="btn-group-toggle mr-2 p-4" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label
      *ngFor="let day of frequencyDays; let i = index"
      (click)="onChangeCheckbox(i)"
      class="btn btn-primary mr-2"
    >
      <input [value]="day.id" type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" />
      {{ day.name }}
    </label>
  </div>

  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

Parent knows the value:
<pre>{{ myForm.value | json }}</pre>
```

Then, in the controller, just create a new `FormControl`:

```js
onChangeCheckbox(index: number) {
 const checkArray: FormArray = this.myForm.get('frequencyInterval') as FormArray;   
 checkArray.push(new FormControl({ day: this.frequencyDays[index] }))
}
```

Not sure why you need an `input` for displaying the days, why not a `button`?

Comment: I have multiple lists to use *ngFor, and for that, I wanted to use the same method `onChangeCheckbox`, and in your implementation, you have checked the index against frequencyDays, later I need to check the index against another list too. So, how can it be more generic?